# Httpful and Laravel, error Class 'Httpful' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, httpful

I've installed Httpful as described with Composer adding to composer.json the following:

```
{
    "require": {
        "nategood/httpful": "*"
    }
}
```

I'm using Laravel 4 so i ran `composer install`
I've checked if the plugin is installed and is there, in fact under the vendor folder of laravel i can find it. But i keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'Httpful' not found'
```

I'm missing some steps?

Thank you in advance

Comment: How are you using it? Show us some code, please.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The class related to this package name conflicts with Laravel's Response class, so this is how you use it in Laravel:

```
$url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=22.569719&lon=88.36972";

$response = \Httpful\Request::get($url)->send();

echo $response->body->name."<br>";
echo $response->body->weather[0]->description;
```

The class is not `Httpful`, but `Response`, so you have to add the correct Namespace so it doesn't get confused by Laravel's Response class.

**EDIT:**

In Laravel you can create aliases for classes. Edit your app/config/app.php and in the `aliases` array, add:

```
'aliases' => array(
         ....

     'Httpful'      => '\Httpful\Request',
),
```

And you'll be able to use it this way:

```
$response = Httpful::get($url)->send();
```

Answer (score 6):

You may need to do `composer update` rather than `composer install`.

The difference being `install` will go by whatever is in your `composer.lock` file, while `update` will pick up any new dependencies added into your `composer.json` file, and **then** write those to your `composer.lock` file.

**Note:** `install` should generally be used in production to get the latest from your `composer.lock` file, while `update` is generally a command used in development to get your updated dependencies.

This also means you should add `composer.lock` to your git repository, even tho it's in your `.gitignore` file by default in a new Laravel project.

Comment: Yep i did `composer update` as well... but no luck. Thanks for the explenation between `composer.lock` and `composer.json`